# Month to Month Growth (same column)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have looked at my other solutions and none seem to work for me. I have a very simple question.

I have a table named foreclosures. It has 3 columns named: foreclosures_id, period, foreclosures. Period is the unique primary key. Datatype for foreclosures column is Decimal.

My current query is: 
    SELECT
    MONTHNAME(period) AS Reported_Month,
    YEAR(period) AS Reported_Year,
    FORMAT(foreclosures, 0) AS Foreclosures,

```
(SELECT FORMAT(SUM(f2.foreclosures),0) FROM foreclosures f2
WHERE f2.period <= f1.period AND f1.foreclosures IS NOT NULL)  
AS YTD_Total,

MONTHNAME(DATE_SUB(period, INTERVAL 2 MONTH))  AS Real_Month,
YEAR(DATE_SUB(period, INTERVAL 2 MONTH))  AS Real_Year

FROM foreclosures f1;
```

I am trying to produce the following "Growth" column. Please help?

```
    +----------------+---------------+--------------+------------+
    | Reported_Month | Reported_Year | Foreclosures | Growth %  |
    +----------------+---------------+--------------+------------+
    | January        |          2016 |          201 |            |
    | February       |          2016 |          332 | 65.2%      |
    | March          |          2016 |          240 | -27.7%     |
    | April          |          2016 |          369 | 53.8%      |
    +----------------+---------------+--------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the foreclosures for the previous period using similar logic to the cumulative sum:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(period) AS Reported_Month,
       YEAR(period) AS Reported_Year,
       FORMAT(foreclosures, 0) AS Foreclosures,
       (SELECT f2.foreclosures
        FROM foreclosures AS f2
        WHERE f2.period < f.period AND
              f.foreclosures IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY f2.period DESC
       ) as prev_foreclosures
FROM foreclosures f;
```

For the growth measure, just apply the arithmetic that you would use for that calculation.

Comment: I figured out a way and your code was a great helpful step in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: @AlessioCantarella . . . Your changes to my code were not an improvement in formatting.  You can read my guidelines for writing SQL code in Chapter 1 of "Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel".  I format my code exactly the way I want it to be written.